# How Do I Change The Test Explorer Window To Display Test Source Information Below, Rather Than Beside?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

My Unit Test Source Info is being displayed side by side, rather than below the tests:

[image: SideBySide]

How do move it so the Test Display is below the tests, rather than beside it?

### Update

Interesting, when I actually am debugging a Unit Test, the Test Explorer shows up correctly:

[image: Above-Below]

Comment: Where is the Test Explorer window placed? My test explorer shows result info "side-by-side" when it is placed in the bottom and below the tests when placed to the left.

Comment: @MAV Thanks for the comment.  It was doc'd to the right, and when I put it in it's own window, it was still not showing correctly, but re-doc-ing it managed to undo whatever was wrong and now it's working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I have found is that Visual Studio automatically decides where to place the divide for this window. You can test this out by undocking the Test Explorer window and then dragging the corner around to resize it. I'm not certain what the ratio is but the details area will snap around either at the bottom or to the right side somewhere around the window being about 1.5 times taller than wider.

This was tested with the community edition of VS 2013. Maybe the "higher" editions allow you to configure this but it doesn't look like the lower editions let you. Hope that helps!

Using 2019 Community Edition, I was able to undock and achieve this.

[image]

Then I put the undocked item back into my main IDE window and it remained like that.

Comment: Something weird must have been going on with my VS, because this was not the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: So if you undock the test explorer and make the window very tall and narrow then very wide and short the layout stays the same? I'm just curios more than anything. Also, are you using the community edition or one of the paid versions?

Comment: It is working now... I did end up seeing some errors in my Activity log.  I'm guessing that something failed to load, and the logic that automatically adjusts the window wasn't getting triggered.

Comment: Same thing here (with VS17). Restarting VS fixed it.

Comment: I'm using VS2019 Enterprise and I have the same problem - it's really annoying, especially if the test names are long. If anyone finds an actual solution I'd be really pleased.

Comment: Tried in VS2022 and when I docked it back into the main window the Test Detail Summary pane moved back to the right hand side .  Still, it's good to know that undocking and resizing the window will display the details on the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

It's a very crazy design of VS. I have to try many ways to see why this happens. And finally, this causes by the wrapping up design. There is a line to separate the result and the test when you dock it, take a look at the pictures:
[image: When_you_dock_the_test_explorer]

[image: drag_the_line_up]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Normally I keep everything (Solution Explorer, Team Explorer, Text Explorer) always on the right hand side. Taking the Test Explorer window and Docking it to the right fixed the problem.  I ended up having to doc everything else back into it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hover your mouse at the bottom of Test Explorer and drag it up. You can see Test Details summary below of your test regardless of Run or Debug mode.